# Query posts by taxonomy term name

Tags: query-posts, taxonomy

I would love to get the list of posts by their custom taxonomy (=store) name.

Here is what I have so far, but it is not working.

Please help with the code.

$mystorename is a variable holding the name of the store i want to query by.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

```
$args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'store',
        'field' => 'name',
        'terms' => $mystorename
    )
)
);

$postslist = get_posts( $args );if(count($postslist) > 0){ ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if the get_posts function supports the tax_query. You might want to try creating a new WP_Query object instead.

```
$args = array(
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'store',
        'field' => 'name',
        'terms' => $mystorename
        )
    )
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);
if ( $query -> have_posts() ) : while ( $query -> have_posts() ) : $query -> the_post(); ?>
    <!-- post -->
<?php endwhile; ?>
    <!-- post navigation -->
<?php else: ?>
    <!-- no posts found -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: the query you posted above kept giving me an error ("expected )") on the line of the last "array(".I had no idea what was wrong, so I abandoned it and went for the code below, which works perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
 $args=array(
  'store' => $mystoreslug,
'post_type' => 'post',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'caller_get_posts'=> 1
);
$my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {?>

 <div class="itembox">
 <h1>Store Coupons</h1>

<div class="itemboxinner">

 <?php while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
   <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php         the_title_attribute(); ?>"><h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3></a></p>
  <?php
 endwhile;
}
wp_reset_query();  
?>'
```

Answer (score 0):

How about...

```
$args = array(
    'store' => $mystorename,
);
$postslist = query_posts( $args );
wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: Explain **why** that could solve the problem.

Comment: Query posts should be used last resort, use get_posts instead. Should $mystorename be a slug, id, display name? explain