# custom post type category count shortcode

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, shortcode, count

I'd like to create a shortcode that would display the post count for a specific category within a custom post type. I've been trying to alter the code below but need some help. Could anyone let me know how to tweak so that the shortcode is for a specific custom post type.

```
// Add Shortcode to show posts count inside a category
function category_post_count( $atts ) {

    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'category' => null
    ), $atts );

    // get the category by slug.
    $term = get_term_by( 'slug', $atts['category'], 'category');

    return ( isset( $term->count ) ) ? $term->count : 0;
}
add_shortcode( 'category_post_count', 'category_post_count' );
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you would be better off using `get_posts` or a `new WP_Query` instead of `get_term_by`. That would allow you to get posts for your custom post type, and then filter by taxonomy/term name.

If you're comfortable enough with WP Query you could try something like this: [Query posts by taxonomy term name](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/64358/query-posts-by-taxonomy-term-name)

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you're using the shortcode inside the loop, you could try the code below. Failing that, your best bet is to get to grips with WP_Query as suggested in another answer.

Add to functions.php

```
function category_post_count( $atts ) {

    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'category' => null,
        'type' => null
    ), $atts );

    $term = get_term_by( 'slug', $atts['category'], 'category');
    $tpt = $atts['type'];

    if( get_post_type() == $tpt ) {
        return $term->count;
    }

}
add_shortcode( 'category_post_count', 'category_post_count' );
```

Typical usage

```
[category_post_count category="category_slug" type="post_type"]
```

Comment: Thanks for providing the above code. It is within the loop but for some reason the above did not work? I have a custom post type, and have a handful of categories for the custom post type. Wanted to display the category count number on the page with a shortcode. But for some reason it's not pulling anything.

Comment: If it didn't display anything, make sure you've replaced `post_type` with the correct `post_type` - if both the `category_slug` and `post_type` are entered correctly, there's no reason why it wouldn't work. Can you double check? Correct usage should look like `[category_post_count category="genre" type="movies"]` where `genre` would be the slug of a category and `movies` is the name of your custom post type.

Comment: Yes unfortunately the slug and post type are all correct in my shortcode. Not sure what's going on? Been searching for different solution today.